# Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(...) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, cudnn

**I run my code on tensorflow 2.1.0 Anaconda with CUDA Toolkit 10.1 CUDNN 7.6.0 (Windows 10) and it returns a issue**

```
F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

**My GPU : GT940MX Compute Capability 5.0**

**I already run the nvcc -V and it returns :**

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Feb__8_19:08:26_Pacific_Standard_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.105
```

**This is the full result :**

```
2020-08-05 10:05:48.368012: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:00.488544: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.153611: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.8605GHz coreCount: 4 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2020-08-05 10:06:48.164731: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.245826: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.296245: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.338860: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.439393: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.489830: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.941872: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:48.946651: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-05 10:06:48.951881: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-08-05 10:06:48.979077: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x23d29b660d0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-05 10:06:48.985680: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-08-05 10:06:48.990616: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1716] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce 940MX computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 0.8605GHz coreCount: 4 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 37.33GiB/s
2020-08-05 10:06:49.003356: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:49.009869: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:49.014858: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:49.020699: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:49.028876: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:49.033607: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:49.039192: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:48] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-08-05 10:06:49.045288: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1858] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-08-05 10:06:49.218497: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1257] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-08-05 10:06:49.223536: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1263]      0
2020-08-05 10:06:49.226857: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1276] 0:   N
2020-08-05 10:06:49.230413: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1402] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 1460 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2020-08-05 10:06:49.244107: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x23d301b8fa0 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-08-05 10:06:49.250377: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce 940MX, Compute Capability 5.0
2020-08-05 10:06:49.446601: F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
```

**What are the issues and how to fix it?**

Comment: The version of tensorflow you have has  been built without  support for your GPU

Comment: @talonmies I have been meet Tensorflow requirements(Cuda compute capability >3.5)

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem. @talonmies please provide info if you can which tensorflow version will be compatible because on the tensorflow website it was said that version 2.3 will be ok with CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6?

Comment: It isn't whether a particular release of Tensorflow can theoretically support your GPU. It is whether the people than built the binary version you have installed chose to compile in support for your GPU. That question needs to be posed to the people who built the binary you have.

Comment: @talonmies Can i run the tensorflow by build it from source with bazel?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry. I can tell you exactly what the problem is at the GPU level, but I know nothing (or really care) about Tensorflow, I'm afraid

Comment: @talonmies no problem, thank you

Comment: I tried both:
1.GTX 960M+ cuDNN7.4(for CUDA10.0)+CUDA10.1+tensorflow2.3
2.GTX 960M+ cuDNN7.6(for CUDA10.1)+CUDA10.1+tensorflow2.3
the same issue remains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is an issue with Python 3.8 and Tensorflow 2.3. I tried the tensorflow 2.3.0 with python 3.7, but it returns an error with python 3.7 because python38.dll (I don't remember exactly the error and i already delete the env), anyway i used python 3.7 on anaconda env and installed tensorflow 2.1.0 with pip and it works.

I posted the question too in github and this question is answered in github https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/42052

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The following combination seemed to have worked for me...

GPU: GeForce GTX 750 Ti, python 3.7.8, tf version 2.1.1, cuda-v7.6.5.32

Answer (score 3):

As per the screenshot below, **`Tensorflow Versions 2.1, 2.2 and 2.3`** work with **cuDNN version of 7.4** but **`cuDNN version of your GPU is 7.6`**.

[image]

That might be, most probably, the reason for the error.

Solution is to downgrade **`cuDNN Version`** of your **`GPU`**.

Existing Version of **`cuDNN`** can be uninstalled through the **`Windows Control Panel`** by using the **`Programs and Features widget`**.

New Version of cuDNN can be installed as shown in this [NVIDIA Installation Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#install-linux).

Also, please refer this [Github Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17422) to know more on how to downgrade cuDNN Version.

The above screenshot has been taken from this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).

Comment: But there is no cuDNN 7.4 that support CUDA 10.1 @Tensorflow Support

Comment: You can try downgrading cuDNN Version to 7.4.

Comment: I tried the cuDNN 7.4 for **CUDA 10.1 (because there is no cuDNN 7.4 for CUDA 10.1)** and it returns the **same** issue `F .\tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:232] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
(D:\Tensorflow\anaconda) PS D:\Tensorflow\TensorFlow-2.x-YOLOv3>`

Comment: I tried the cuDNN 7.4 for CUDA 10.1 (because there is no cuDNN 7.4 for CUDA 10.1) ==> This sentence is bit confusing. Can you please rephrase it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry i mean : I tried the cuDNN 7.4 for CUDA 10.0 (because there is no cuDNN 7.4 for CUDA 10.1) and it returns the same issue @Tensorflow Support

Comment: 2023 update: tensorflow-gpu is a [deprecated library](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-gpu/). Use regular tensorflow instead

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, my cuDNN is 8.0.2.
As you say, there is no cuDNN 7.4 for CUDA 10.1.
So, I tried the cuDNN 7.5 for CUDA 10.1 and it works!!!!
Hope my experience can help someone else.    :)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seem like some cuDNN only support by some specific versions of tensorflow.

As a Window user this is how I do:

1. [Check which version that which Tensorflow and CUDA version combinations are compatible](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations) (you can click on other OS on the left)
2. As Rock Jefferson comment you can use cuDNN 7.5 for CUDA 10.1. It work for me.
   [Download here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)

Try it. Hope it useful for U guy.

Comment: I was having this problem with CUDA 10.1 and cuDNN 7.6.5 (the latest version listed to be compatible with 10.1). I tried downgrading to cuDNN 7.5.1 but it had the same problem. Same for 7.5.0.